# ColumnsofType Record not returning any columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I've got a table full of different data types, including records, that I want to extract all column names of records to then use in an expand function. I've included a screenshot of a column containing record's however,[image] when I use this `= Table.ColumnsOfType(#"Expanded fields", {type record})`, it returns an empty list .

[image]

I've tried looking through the entire column to see if there was anything different but its all record types. Any help please.

EDIT:
[image]

Error using Table.TransformColumnTypes

Comment: None of the columns in your screenshot are of the `record` type. One of the columns contains a list of records, but the column is typed as `any`. You can write a routine that looks at the contents of the first `n` cells in a column, and detect contents in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record is not a valid type to search for. And judging by your image, your type is Type.Any as denoted by the ABC123

You best bet is to unpivot all the columns (perhaps those starting with a certain prefix) then on the new Value column, expand like so

```
#"PriorStepNameHere" = .... , 
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"PriorStepNameHere", "Value"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "Value", ExpandList,ExpandList)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Table.ColumnsOfType function is not properly identifying the columns in your table that contain records.One possible reason for this is that the column's datatype is not properly set as 'record'. Another possible reason could be that the data in the columns is not structured properly and hence it is not being identified as a record. You can try to use the Table.TransformColumnTypes function to convert the column's datatype to 'record' and see if that resolves the issue.
If the issue still persists, please share the sample data and the code you are using.

Comment: I've added an edit of the error I'm getting trying to use Table.TransformColumnTypes